# NFC Security for Payment

Tags: wireless, security-theater, nfc, payment

During an offline transaction, the Point-of-Sale has no internet connection,
and so the payment terminal cannot verify if the client’s payment
device has been revoked.

A malicious person can use a revoked bank card to perform unauthorized
transactions.

How can this be prevented?

Comment: Would you mind expanding this question to cover credit cards in general and not just NFC? I was thinking about this exact question but involving swiped mag-stripe cards instead of NFC.

Answer (score 1):

If the transaction is truly offline, also called store and forward in the retail space, then there is a lot of inherent risk the business is accepting. That is why almost all in person transactions involve an online authorization, which contacts the issuing bank to verify the transaction details.

I am not aware of any way to mitigate that risk in a true offline transaction scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply ,really it's include inherent risk .

Comment: The way you mitigate the risk isn't technical. You build it into your business cost model, either directly or through insurance.